# Is it better if each integrated circuit has a dedicated voltage regulator?

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, esp32, ldo

I have a circuit consisting of an ESP32 microcontroller and some integrated circuits. Is it better if each integrated circuit has its own voltage regulator?

[image: schema]

Example:

[image: circuit]

**Full circuit after modification :**
[image: Full circuit after modification]

Comment: It depends. Not much advantage if you're going to be using linear regulators anyway, but I would advise changing to switching regulators, and then there may be advantages if you need high current on any of the chips.

Comment: Switching regulators would be good, but wouldn't there be confusion between the integrated circuits as I differentiated the GND for each circuit as well

Comment: What do you mean confusion?

Comment: @Hearth I meant Noise between the integrated circuits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason to do what you are doing is the current is too high for one linear regulator but you insist on using only linear regulators.

If your goal is noise, then using separate linear regulators is one step but sufficient on its own because the linear regulator's bandwidth, though higher than a switching regulator, is not nearly fast enough to respond to high frequency noise which will pass straight through the regulator in both directions. Filtering needs to be added as well in that case.

> but wouldn't there be confusion between the integrated circuits as I differentiated the GND for each circuit as well

Unless the circuits are simply not interconnected or are connected through methods providing galvanic isolation, GND and AGND must connect together somewhere. The circuit will not work otherwise. The distinction between GND and AGND is more a matter of physical PCB layout than anything else.

For example, if you have noise sensitive circuitry using AGND, and noise insensitive circuitry using GND, the AGND and GND still need to be connected together somewhere unless the sensitive and insensitive circuits were not interconnected at all or only interconnected through galvanic isolators. Signals running between the two circuits over non-galvanically isolated connections require a return current path which they won't have if you leave GND and AGND disconnected.

But you don't want the GND currents of the insensitive circuitry flowing in the AGND currents of the sensitive circuitry so you clump the insensitive circuitry together and the sensitive circuitry together and connect the GND and AGND together. That way, insensitive circuitry can communicate amongst itself and the ground currents don't need to flow under or near the sensitive circuitry.

In practice when you do this, you don't usually make separate ground plane for GND and AGND with a small bridge in between to connect them. This is because if you run an interconnection over the gap in the ground planes, the signal must flow in a big loop to the bridge connection between ground planes to return. Big loops have high inductance and current flowing that way makes lots of noise.

So you must only route interconnections over the bridge where the planes connect, or more commonly, you just make one big plane but keeps the sensitive and insensitive circuits separated.

Comment: I connected GND with AGND with zero resistance, I took your comments into consideration and modified the circuit, see above, is that enough?

Comment: @RACHIDBENABDELMALEK Just connect the GND and AGND directly on the schematic. If you do it through a zero ohm resistor then you must have only a single point connection which will aggravate your routing. If you just connect it directly then it can appear as a single plane in your layout software. After that it's up to you to group the two different parts when laying out your PCB so that currents in the GND and AGND plane don't needlessly interfere with each other (run under parts of the circuit that do not use them).

Comment: @RACHIDBENABDELMALEK Also, LC input filters are kind of pointless for linear regulators. Remember that the linear regulator is going to burn off the excess voltage as heat anyways. That means the zero DC voltage drop of an L is pointless. You are safer just going with an RC since the resistor will dissipate some of the heat so the linear regulator doesn't have to. It will also avoid noise peaking and avoid high frequency noise from passing straight through the interwinding capacitance of an inductor. You choose the R so that the current does not drop more voltage than your outputs needs.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain more how I can choose R

Comment: High R gives better filtering but you don't want the R to be too high or else at your peak current draw the voltage drops below your desired output. So \$R < (V_{in} - V_{out} - V_{dropout})/I_{max}\$. Where \$I_{max}\$ is the peak current draw of your circuit. That way, at the peak current drawn, there is still enough voltage remaining at the input to the regulator that it won't enter dropout so it can still regulate.

Comment: But ( Vin = Vout + Vdropout ), We will get a zero equation

Comment: @RACHIDBENABDELMALEK You're not understanding something. Take a closer look at it. Use real numbers like 1V dropout, 3V output and a battery input that varies between 4 and 5V.

Comment: I will use this LDO ( XC6210B302MR-G ) when : Vdropout = 0.25 ,Vout = 3V , Vin = V_lithiumBattery = 3.7V and Imax = 500mA, I will get: R = 0.9 Ohm

Comment: Yes. Note that lithium batteries, like all batteries, will decrease in voltage as they discharge. They also experience voltage droop when they supply current due to internal impedance. 3.7V is the nominal voltage at open circuit, not the voltage near empty under load which would be your worst case low voltage.